# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' in JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, sql

I have the problem with running a script in JMeter.
I get the following error message

```
Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver'
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

[image: Screehshot]

Comment: Please provide more info (driver version, DB version, connection settings...) .

Answer (score 3):

As per [Let's Start](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#lets_start) chapter of JMeter Getting Started Guide

> If you want to perform JDBC testing, then you will, of course, need the appropriate JDBC driver from your vendor. **JMeter does not come with any JDBC drivers**.

So make sure to download [Oracle JDBC Driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/jdbcdriver-ucp-downloads.html) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath).

And don't forget to restart JMeter to pick the .jar up.

Also change "Validation Query" in the [JDBC Connection Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) to `select 1 from dual`

More information: [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/real-secret-building-database-test-plan-jmeter/)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jars you want to use and drop in this location:

JMETER_HOME/lib

Then restart jmeter.